# d3: Optionally add child elements based on node content in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

Using the force layout in d3, I can happily add nodes as, say, an SVG group of a circle and some text:

```
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node");
node.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 5);
node.append("svg:text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.nodetext });
```

However, I would like to *optionally* add another element to the group, dependent on the node data: so if the data for this node contains an "image" attribute, I'd like to add a new child-element (an svg:image). It's easy to add the svg:image to all nodes (I just do it as I've done the circle and text above). It's also easy to dynamically change an attribute of an element you've already created (by having a function as the attribute's value, as per `text` above). I do not know how to add an `svg:image` child element *only if* the data contains an `image` attribute. What's the best way of achieving this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try [selection.filter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter):

```
node.filter(function(d) { return d.image; }).append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.image; })
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 16);
```