# d3: Optionally add child elements based on node content in force layout - when filter is not the solution

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, force-layout

I am trying to make a possible solution for this question: [d3 force layout with node groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486808/d3-force-layout-with-node-groups)

I have a JSON something like this:

```
{
    nodes: [
        {
            label: "x"
            inputs: [],
            outputs: ["a"]
        },
        {
            label: "y"
            inputs: ["b"],
            outputs: []
        },
        ...
    ],
    links: [
        {
            source: 0, //x
            sourceIndex: 0, //x.outputs.a
            target: 1, //y
            targetIndex: 0 //y.inputs.b
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

I want to build an SVG for each node something like this:

```
    <g class="component worker" transform="translate(0,0)">
        <use class="container" xlink:href="#container"/>
        <use class="icon" xlink:href="#worker"/>
        <text class="label" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle" dy="40">Worker</text>
        <g class="input" transform="translate(-31,-16)">
            <use class="port" xlink:href="#port">
                <title>stdin</title>
            </use>
            <use y="8" class="port" xlink:href="#port"/>
            <use y="16" class="port" xlink:href="#port"/>
            <use y="24" class="port" xlink:href="#port"/>
            <use y="32" class="port" xlink:href="#port"/>
        </g>
        <g class="output" transform="translate(31,16)">
            <use class="port" xlink:href="#port">
                <title>stdout</title>
            </use>
            <use y="-8" class="port" xlink:href="#port"/>
            <use y="-16" class="port" xlink:href="#port"/>
            <use y="-24" class="port" xlink:href="#port"/>
            <use y="-32" class="port" xlink:href="#port"/>
        </g>
    </g>
```

I have the following js code to build the SVG:

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node").data(this.data.nodes).enter().append("g").attr({
        "class": function (d) {
            return d.groups.join(" ");
        }
    }).call(force.drag);
    node.append("use").attr({
        "class": "container",
        "xlink:href": "#container"
    });
    node.append("use").attr({
        "class": "icon",
        "xlink:href": function (d) {
            return d.icon;
        }
    });
    node.append("text").attr({
        "class": "label",
        "text-anchor": "middle",
        "alignment-baseline": "middle",
        dy: 40
    }).text(function (d) {
        return d.label
    });

    node.append("g").attr({
        "class": "input",
        transform: "translate(-31,-16)"
    });

    node.append("g").attr({
        "class": "output",
        transform: "translate(31,16)"
    });
```

Now what I am missing are the inputs and outputs. I don't know how to iterate those properties of the nodes and how to append them one by one with the fluent interface of d3.js. I checked [d3: Optionally add child elements based on node content in force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12787769/d3-optionally-add-child-elements-based-on-node-content-in-force-layout) but filtering does not work here, because we are talking about iterating a collection, and not about checking the existence of a property. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested selection for this.

I'm assuming for the inputs you want to append an item for each member of the `inputs` array in your node's data, and likewise for outputs.

For example, the inputs:

```
node.append("g").attr({
    "class": "input",
    transform: "translate(-31,-16)"
})
.selectAll('SOME_THING')
  .data(function(d) { return d.inputs; })
  .enter().append('SOME_THING')
```

Where `'SOME_THING'` is the element you want to append (perhaps the `<use>` though it's unclear from your example output where those get mapped to).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with `each()`:

```
    node.each(function (d) {
        var node = d3.select(this);
        var inputs = node.append("g").attr({
            "class": "input",
            transform: "translate(-31,-16)"
        });
        d.inputs.forEach(function (name, index) {
            inputs.append("use").attr({
                y: -8 * index,
                "xlink:href": "#port"}).append("title").text(name);
        });
    });
```

But I'll use jshanley's solution, I guess that is the d3 way... :-)

```
    var inputs = node.append("g").attr({
        "class": "input",
        transform: "translate(-31,-16)"
    });
    inputs.selectAll("use").data(function (d) {
        return d.inputs;
    }).enter().append("use").attr({
        y: function (d, index) {
            return -8 * index;
        },
        "xlink:href": "#port"
    }).append("title").text(String);
```